# how much work is done by calling vector.size()?

Tags: c++

Is it a simple getter? or is it calculating every time?

If I have a for loop like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myVector.size(); i++) { }
```

where I only need to use the size once, would it be better to calculate this once before the loop and store it in a variable? Or is size() just a simple getter and it would make little difference?

Comment: Keep in mind that calculating it before hand is only valid if the size doesn't change in the loop.

Comment: MSVC 2010 implementation is the difference between end pointer and first pointer of the internal array. Nevertheless I smell premature-optimization here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is implementation defined. Assuming that implementations want to provide efficient standard libraries, the two most probable implementations are:

- subtracting the pointer pointing to the beginning of the storage from the pointer pointing to one after the end of the storage, and returning the result of that computation.
- returning a size variable that is kept in sync for every operation in the vector.

In any case the standard requires the complexity to be constant, and you should not really worry about it. Also compilers often optimize enough to make no difference to storing your size on your own.

Answer (score 5):

Use iterators instead of such a loop for more flexibility and genrosity:

```
std::vector<int>::const_iterator iter = myVector.begin();

for(iter; iter!= myVector.end(); ++iter)
{

}
```

This ensures that if you change your container at later stage of development you have less tightly coupled code.

Comment: I got a fever, and the only prescription is more `auto`!

Comment: I can prescribe you that: for(auto it = std::begin(v); it != std::end(v); ++it) {}

Comment: I can prescribe you `for( auto it : v ) { }`. But while this is a good advice to give, I doubt that it is really what the OP wanted to know.

Comment: This doesn't have much to do with the question. Just as `size()` could be implemented as a subtraction, `end()` could be implemented as an addition. Also, in some situations you might need the index in the loop, so using iterators would be more awkward.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you are actually wondering whether the compiler can figure out that the value returned by the `size()` function never changes and *hoist* it out of the loop. While this seems sensible, the compiler would have to be able to prove that the hoisting produces the exact same behaviour as the version you have written (i.e. "as if" `size()` was called every time), and there are limits to how far the compiler can see, or indeed to how far this is actually provable.

Therefore, if you know that you aren't changing the size of the container, you should write the hoist manually:

```
// index version:
for (std::size_t i = 0; end = v.size(); i != end; ++i) { work_with(v[i]); }

// iterator version:
for (auto it = v.begin(), end = v.end(); it != end; ++it) { work_with(*it); }
```

Calls to `std::vector::size()` have constant complexity, i.e. their cost is independent of the number of elements in the vector, but there may be a cost nonetheless. In the best circumstances you are simply *reading* a variable (so there's no difference in the hoisted and non-hoisted version of loops bar one copy), but it's also feasible that the implementation performs a pointer subtraction.

Answer (score 1):

In every implementation I've looked at, it's calculated every time - in O(1) - by subtracting begin from end.  So, it makes very little difference.  The compiler may or may not optimise away the "calculation", but the time is so miniscule as to be irrelevant for all but the most desperate sitatuations.

Use whatever's more maintainable in your opinion: whatever reads best, localises the logic best etc..  It's arguably noteworthy that in using size() you ensure you accurately track the end of the vector even if there are deletions or insertions made inside the loop body, so there can be functional reasons to prefer (or avoid) calling size() repeatedly.

Note that for STL lists size() is NOT constant time - it's linear.

Comment: so better to store it? or does the compiler do something clever that would negate this attempt at optimisation?

Comment: this means that it is computed in constant time, storing it won't give you less complexity

Comment: @SirYakalot: very probably, and if the compiler did nothing it wouldn't make a tangible difference in 99.9999999% of cases.

Comment: I would expect the compiler to optimize it so I would call size() and not worry about it. If it is a performance critical loop (unlikely), profile the release build to see which one is faster.

Comment: "for STL lists size() is NOT constant time - it's linear" - although it's constant in C++11 (some of the `splice` functions lose out and can no longer be constant).

Answer (score 1):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/size/ suggests that the complexity of the operation is constant. This means that the size won't be recalculated each time you call `size()`, or that the overhead is in most cases negligible. So using it like it's in your code is okay: this won't be the bottleneck of your code. (Unless this is a tight inner loop, where every optimization is going to bring a lot.)

Moreover, you'll be on a safer (but not completely safe!) side if the vector is going to be changed inside the loop.

Comment: What constant says in this case that the time taken to compute the size doesn't depend on the number of elements. The computation may, however, be expensive enough to account for the majority of the time spent in the loop. That means you shouldn't compute the suze every iteration unless you have to.

Comment: @Dietmar: you are basically right. But I wanted to express the idea that `size()` doesn't contribute much to the computational complexity of the code, so optimizing it to a local variable should be a part of fine-tuning. In usual cases it should be okay to leave it as it is.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the implementation of vector::size()

```
size_type size() const
{   // return length of sequence
        return (_Mylast - _Myfirst);
}
```

where _Mylast and _Myfirst are pointers.

Its just a pointer arithmetic and should be an atomic operation. Hence it shouldn't be an overhead!

Comment: This is one implementation and it is bad enough. Other implementation are optimized for mor interesting use cases (e.g. quick swapping of vectors) and may spent more time accessing the size.

Comment: I got it from the MSVC 9.0 library! :)

Comment: There are at least five different standard C++ library implementations I'm aware of, not counting my own. ... and I wrote several versions of std::vector (but only one of std::vector<bool>).

Comment: Oh okay! Good to know that. Thanks! I guess the answer should be that it is implementation specific!

Comment: It says in my response that there are different implementations but I'm indeed not calling it out to be implementation specific. However, computing the suze() just once will use the std::vector efficiently on all implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Computing the `size()` for a `std::vector` takes constant time but the computation may be more involved than the difference between two pointers. Although this seems like a cheap computation it adds constraints on the available registers. Also, other implementations of `std::vector` take even more effort in `size()` but make other operations more efficient.

For example, for many use cases it is better to represent a `std::vector` with just one pointer to the start of the range and the control data prepended to this range. Oddly enough this happens how memory allocated using an array allocation is often layed out anyway. The control data would contain two pointers (one to the end of the range, the other to the capacity). Getting the size in this case consists of an address adjustment (with fixed size, though), a pointer dereference, and a subtraction. Still not a lot but the less you do in a [tight] loop, the faster it runs (in most cases).

The upshot is: get the `size()` and the `end()` just once unless you container is changing its size. If it is changing the size it depends on the kind of container whether you should recompute things: e.g. for a `std::list` you dont need to get the `end()` again (and you don't want to get its `size()` at all inless you absolutely have to). I seem to recall that Scott Meyers has a discussion of this topic in "Effective STL" but I don't recall whether he says what I just did (or if he is just wrong ;).